# Apply with_items on multiple tasks

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to apply a list of items to multiple tasks in an Ansible playbook? To give an example:

```
- name: download and execute
  hosts: server1
  tasks:
  - get_url: url="some-url/{{item}}" dest="/tmp/{{item}}"
    with_items:
    - "file1.sh"
    - "file2.sh"
  - shell: /tmp/{{item}} >> somelog.txt
    with_items:
    - "file1.sh"
    - "file2.sh"
```

Is there some syntax to avoid the repetition of the item-list?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As of today you can use `with_items` with `include`, so you'd need to split your playbook into two files:

```
- name: download and execute
  hosts: server1
  tasks:
  - include: subtasks.yml file={{item}}
    with_items:
    - "file1.sh"
    - "file2.sh"
```

and `subtasks.yml`:

```
- get_url: url="some-url/{{file}}" dest="/tmp/{{file}}"
- shell: /tmp/{{file}} >> somelog.txt
```

There was a [request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13262) to make `with_items` applicable to `block`, but the Ansible team has said **it will never be supported**.

Comment: Re. making `with_items` applicable to `block`: This feature is not implemented in Ansible as explained in the feature request above. That explanation dates up to 2018-09-27, so Ansible up to v2.5.5 doesn't have this `with_items`+`block` feature; it doesn't look like it'll be added any time soon if ever.

Comment: Latest `include` module documentation (as of v2.9) suggests that the `include` module will be deprecated in the near future, and recommends using `include_tasks` or `import_tasks` modules instead.

Comment: `include` got removed in v2.16, you should use the alternative `include_tasks`, `import_tasks` or `import_playbook`

Answer (score 5):

You have the possibility to define a yaml list in a variables file:

```
---
myfiles:
- "file1.sh"
- "file2.sh"
...
```

and then you can use

```
with_items: "{{ myfiles }}"
```

in the task.