# Ansible with_items and register

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible and trying to create a playbook that will extend the expiration date on a list of user accounts which already have a specific an expiration date set. Any accounts with a different date or set to never should not be affected.

While the first parts executes ok, it appears to overwriting the value of expiration_date_{{item}} with each user.

Any ideas how to go about this.

```
---  
- hosts: all  
  become: true  
  tasks:  
  - name: Check accounts expiration dates  
    shell: "chage -l  {{ item }} | grep 'Account expires' | cut -d':' -f2"  
    args:  
      warn: no  
    register: expiration_date_{{item}}  
    with_items:  
      - user1  
      - user2  
      - user3  

  - name: Extend expiration date  
    user: name={{ item }} expires=1540944000  
    when: "'May 31' in expiration_date_{{item}}.stdout"  
    with_items:  
      - user1  
      - user2  
      - user3 
...
```

Comment: try to format the code in your post. I dont know ansible but I feel like you should show a little bit more code  to see what have you being trying-

Comment: Please see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512443/register-variables-in-with-items-loop-in-ansible-playbook/29564339) on register with loops, and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on asking good questions. Also, [here's a cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) for markdown formatting. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think that you basically want to loop over 2 tasks instead of one. In that case you can create a separate file (in YAML syntax) with those two tasks and use the option `include_tasks` in your main playbook and loop over it.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39041069/9686925)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I cannot use -with_items inside a block...  ERROR!  'with_items; is not a valid attribute for a Block

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. This is actually a feature that is to be implemented in the future. For now, I think this might be your best answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/39041069/9686925](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39041069/9686925)